# How to use Node.js with Nuxt.js?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm have server.js file in directory "Server", which connected with Nuxt.js

```
server.js

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/api/data', (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Hello from server!' });
});

module.exports = {
  path: '/api',
  handler: app
};
```

```
nuxt.config.ts

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },

  serverMiddleware: [
    '~/server/server.js'
  ]

})
```

I tried send GET:http://localhost:3000/api/data in Insomnia and recieved:

```
{
    "url": "/api/data",
    "statusCode": 404,
    "statusMessage": "Page not found: /api/data",
    "message": "Page not found: /api/data",
    "stack": "",
    "data": {
        "path": "/api/data"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to proxy the requests to `/api` to the express.

---

For example

there is a [hello-world](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) API which is powered by the express

add a domain for your dev env, such as `example.test`

register it in your nginx config

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .example.test;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    # requests to `/api/` will be proxy to express
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    location ~* ^/api/ {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3001;
    }

    # requests to `/` will be proxy to Nuxt
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```

add a local domain name resolve in your `host` file

```
127.0.0.1 example.test
```

`http://example.test/api/hello-world`

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3001

app.get('/api/hello-world', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

and there is a Nuxt3 page

`http://example.test/hello-world`

```
/pages/hello-world.vue

<script lang="ts" setup>

const { data } = useFetch('http://example.test/api/hello-world')

</script>
```

---

Since Nuxt3 comes up with [`/api`](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server)

Consider the `/api` which is powered by the `express` and the '/api' which is powered by the Nuxt3 as two different project